# Problems with Backgroundworker, GUI is hanged

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am using a background worker below an a form, and when i click a button it should generate a document, but the GUI hangs , i don't know why it does that, because i feel i m using the backgroundworker right.. can anybody helps in this ?

```
  private void btn_GenerateRevDoc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker_DoWork);
        DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged);
        DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
        if (Db.docVersionHistory != null && Db.docVersionHistory.Count > 0)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Title = "Export Review To";
            sfd.Filter = "Word files (*.doc)|*.doc|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            sfd.FilterIndex = 1;
            sfd.FileName = "";

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {


                if (!DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker.IsBusy)
                    DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(sfd.FileName);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Review Records were found!");
        }

    }
    void DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                     {

                         DocumentsNavigator.GenerateWordRevisionHistoryDoc(DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker, versionsList, Db, (string)(e.Argument));

                     }));
        }
        else
        {
            DocumentsNavigator.GenerateWordRevisionHistoryDoc(DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker, versionsList, Db, (string)(e.Argument));

        }
    }
```

Comment: if (!DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker.IsBusy) doesn't make sense as you are creating a new backgroundworker everytime button is clicked

Comment: you have the c#-4.0 and c#-3.0. Is that really necessary? Isn't the c# tag enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't quite grasp how the `BackgroundWorker` is supposed to be used, and what the `Invoke` method does.

The `Invoke` method causes the code be called on the UI thread. So, don't pass the `DocumentsNavigator.GenerateWordRevisionHistoryDoc` method through `Invoke`. `RunWorkerAsync` is fine. I don't know what types `versionsList` and `Db` are, but if they are UI objects, you may need to copy the values you need to a new variable. For example, if `versionsList` is a `ListBox`, you should copy the selected values to a new `string[]`, and use that `string[]` as a parameter to your method.

Here's what you think you wanted to do:

- Create new Background worker
- initialize your background worker
- disable the `btn_GenerateRevDoc` button
- Show the `SaveFileDialog`
- Start the BackgroundWorker (`RunWorkerAsync`)
- On the `ProgressChanged` event, if you're displaying a progress bar or
  something, you can update that, this time you do have to passe it
  through the `Invoke` method.
- And on the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, show a messagebox or something,
  and enable the `btn_GenerateRevDoc` button again

Oh, and this line should absolutely be removed:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your background worker you are again forwarding all the work to UI thread that's why your UI is hanging

```
 if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            //this executes the work on UI thread
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                     {

                         DocumentsNavigator.GenerateWordRevisionHistoryDoc(DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker, versionsList, Db, (string)(e.Argument));

                     }));
        }
        else
        {
//it will also be executed on UI thread     
   DocumentsNavigator.GenerateWordRevisionHistoryDoc(DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker, versionsList, Db, (string)(e.Argument));

        }
    }
```

Comment: but it is not the same UI, it is another one, if i understand well

Answer (score 0):

> when i click a button it should generate a document, but the GUI hangs

from your code I can see that you should enter a file name and click ok. Is there a save dialog being opened somewhere?

Try writing the same code without using the background worker. Does it still hang? Also, observed that the condition `if (!DOC_GenerateVersDocBackgroundWorker.IsBusy)` doesn't make sense as you are creating a new backgroundworker everytime button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that You are running the code that hangs the GUI in a worker thread but you do it in an Invoke method.

The Invoke method runs the code in the thread of the GUI and so it hangs.

If you absolutely must call `DocumentsNavigator.GenerateWordRevisionHistoryDoc` in the GUI thread I don't see how you can make this call without hanging the GUI.

Try to rethink your code so you don't have to run any code in the BackgroungWorker in an Invoke method.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing something unsafe.

instead of Invoke try

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)         
{             this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate                      
   {
```

Comment: Invoke alltogether is the problem

Comment: Thats not what I meant about the invoke, I just suggested to make your code more cleaner, you are calling it in a non UI thread thats the problem, the call to generatewordrevistionHistory. You may like to set flags and check for flags instead, good luck

Comment: You're right. As a general rule, independently of this question, it's safer to call BeginInvoke than to call Invoke. I hadn't noticed the MethodInvoker.

Comment: and yet you downgrade my answer :)

Comment: Your answer was technically correct, but it didn't begin to address the bulk of the OP's problem. Using your advice, the UI thread would hang all the same.